# pass object parameter to method in setHeader - camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Camel and trying to find a way to pass object to method in SetHeader.

but i am getting an error,

```
org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed to invoke method: getCustProcessDir('${header.CUST}') on null due to: org.apache.camel.component.bean.ParameterBindingException: Error during parameter binding on method: public java.lang.String CustDao.getCustProcessDir(Cust) at parameter #0 with type: class Cust with value type: class java.lang.String and value: Cust@199b87b5
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.invokeOgnlMethod(BeanExpression.java:430) ~[camel-bean-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.evaluate(BeanExpression.java:164) ~[camel-bean-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
```

codes:

```
fromF("file:C:/Users/a/Documents/Development/input/"
                + "?recursive=false&noop=true&delay=20000&readLockLoggingLevel=WARN&shuffle=true"
                + "&readLock=idempotent&idempotentRepository=#fileRepo&readLockRemoveOnCommit=true&readLockRemoveOnRollback=true&delete=true&moveFailed=%s"
                , "C:/Users/a/Documents/Development/rejected/")
        .routeId("fileMoveRoute")
        .process(exchange -> {
            exchange.getMessage().setHeader("Application_ID", appInfo.getInstanceId());
        })
        .threads(appInfo.getThreadCount())
        .setHeader("CUST", method(CustDao.class, "getInboundCustWithfile('${header.CamelFilePath}')"))
        .setHeader("PROCESS_DIR", method(CustDao.class, "getCustProcessDir('${header.CUST}')"))
        ...
    
public String getCustProcessDir(Cust cust) {
    return appInfo.getDir() + cust.getCustprofid() + "/hold/";
    }   



public class Cust {

  private int custid;
  private String custprofid;
  ...
 
}
```

first `setHeader("CUST"..)` works and i believe that `Header("CUST")` has returned object values.

but I am not sure how it is stored in Camel. I've tried to find them from variables window during debug but was not able to find them. too many variables to look into... Where can i find this Header values during debug?

and how can i pass object values to the method?

```
.setHeader("PROCESS_DIR", method(CustDao.class, "getCustProcessDir('${header.CUST}')"))
```

or is there a better way to pass/handle object during routing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the **single quotes** around expressions like `${header.CUST}` are the problem because the `RuntimeBeanExpressionException` complains that it receives the String `Cust@199b87b5` instead of a `Cust` object.

Have a look at the [Camel docs for Bean binding](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/bean-binding.html). There are no single quotes around method parameter expressions.

About the storage of header variables: they are stored on the [Message object](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.21.0/org/apache/camel/Message.html) of Camel.

```
Exchange -> Message -> Headers
Exchange -> ExchangeProperties
```

Comment: Very nice catch! make sense. don't know why I didn't see that ;) I really appreciate!